# Cannot resolve method 'getId' in 'Object' while looping through enum class values

Tags: java

I want to loop through enum class values like this:

```
Long id = 5L;
String className = "MyEnum";  //here maybe several other enum class name, I get it from controller
Class<?> enumClass = Class.forName("com.example.demo.dictTask." + classname);
Stream.of(enumClass.getEnumConstants()).filter(e -> Objects.equals(e.getId(), id)).findFirst().orElseThrow();
```

I have `getId()` method in my enum classes. But I dont know why `filter()` method in Stream is not working: Cannot resolve method 'getId' in 'Object'.

Here is one of my enum class:

```
public interface MyEnumInterface<K, V> {
    K getId();

    V getName();
} 

@AllArgsConstructor
public enum MyEnum implements MyEnumInterface<Long, String> {

    JAMES(5L, "NBA"),

    MARK(6L, "MLS");

//    ...

    @Getter
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the type to MyEnumInterface will make resolve the `getId()` method

```
Class<? extends MyEnumInterface> strClass = Class.forName("com.example.demo.dictTask." + className).asSubclass(MyEnumInterface.class);
Stream.of(strClass.getEnumConstants())
            .filter(e -> Objects.equals(e.getId(), id))
            .findFirst().orElseThrow();
```

Comment: But then the return type of the Stream() would be MyEnumInterface, I need the return type to be MyEnum.

Comment: i am not sure if you can get it with the type `MyEnum` as this is going to be dynamically determined based on this "className" String - right? 
However, what do you need the specific implementation for? maybe you can continue with the `MyEnumInterface` and use it polymorphically (without knowing the exact implementation. If this would work, you can then even replace the `Class.forName` there with the Factory pattern